Unable to locate package makeinfo
I need to install a cross-compiler for the Pi and I'm following https://xmleye.wordpress.com/2017/10/17/running-uml-rt-models-on-a-raspberry-pi-based-rover/#comments because it's really similar to my project.
I'm new to Linux and was trying to fix this error but I am stuck.
tt@ReNiS ~/crosstool-ng $ sudo apt-get install gperf bison flex makeinfo texinfo help2man
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package makeinfo

After I got this, I ran sudo apt install texinfo to install makefile. I can now find it, but I still get the same result.
tt@ReNiS $ which makeinfo
/usr/bin/makeinfo

I also ran this but it's still not working.
sudo apt update

System info: Linux Mint 18.3 Cinnamon 64bit. kernel 4.19
Can someone help? Thanks!

if which makeinfo already returns /usr/bin/makeinfo, you have already installed it whatever the package name was and where it comes from...

I don't see any problem in this question. Sure, the package name might be different on your distribution, but as you figured out yourself, the package is already installed. So you don't need the sudo apt-get install makeinfo part to succeed. Just remove makeinfo from the command.

For people coming here later. The makeinfo file is provided in Ubuntu based distros (like Mint) by the texinfo package. It's not something you need to install separately.
See deb package contents listing for confirmation https://packages.debian.org/buster/arm64/texinfo/filelist

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
